# How to choose date range in calendar pop-up with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Issue:** I have having trouble using Puppeteer to click on a hotel's webpage's (https://www.hilton.com/en/) calendar pop-up next month button.

[image: Hilton Calendar Pop-up]

---

Code:

This line is not working: `await page.click('[data-testid="calendar-container"] > [class="flex justify-between"] > [class="sr-only"]');`

hilton_constants.js file

```
    START_MONTH: "September",
    START_DAY: 1,
    START_YEAR: 2023,
    END_MONTH: "September",
    END_DAY: 4,
    END_YEAR: 2023,
```

Main Node fx:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const constants = require('./hilton_constants.js');
const fs = require('fs/promises');

// * Main Function
let browser;
async function hiltonScan() {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.setViewport({ width: 750, height: 10700 });

  // Block resources
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', (request) => {
      if (request.resourceType() === 'image' || request.resourceType() === 'font' || request.resourceType() === 'media') {
        request.abort();
      } else {
        request.continue()
      }
  });

  await page.goto('https://www.hilton.com/en/', { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });

  // Fill in Location
  await page.type('[class="form-input w-full"]', "Seattle, WA, USA");

  // Click calendar UI to select dates
  await page.click('[data-testid="search-dates-button"]');
  await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="calendar-container"]');


  // ! This is NOT WORKING - Fill in calendar UI stay dates
  await fill_stayDates(page, constants);


  
  //* Helper function for above: click to the correct starting month
  async function fill_stayDates(page, constants){
    const findMonth = async targetMonth => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        // Not sure if this is causing an error
        const month = await page.$eval('[id^="calendar-month-"]', el => el.textContent);
        if (month.includes(targetMonth)) break;

        //! THIS IS NOT WORKING
        await page.click('[data-testid="calendar-container"] > [class="flex justify-between"] > [class="sr-only"]');
    };

    await findMonth(constants.START_MONTH);
    await chooseDay(constants.START_DAY);
    await findMonth(constants.END_MONTH);
    await chooseDay(constants.END_DAY);

    // click X button to close
    await page.click('[class="stroke-text"]');
  };

  //! this works, comment out for now Click Find a Hotel
  // await page.click('[data-testid="search-submit-button"]');

  // Wait for navigation
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  }
}


// * Call the main function
(async () => {
  console.log('Starting the Hilton scraper program...');
  await hiltonScan()
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
    .finally(() => browser?.close());
})();
```

Comment: [Do not upload images of HTML](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) The HTML can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML in (Firefox|Chrome) Dev Tools (Elements tabs) and add it to your original post, not as a comment

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but often, when Puppeteer's `click` isn't working, you can try `await page.$eval("selector", el => el.click())` which is less fussy about visibility. I assume you have the selector right. Note that `[class=".."]` is very strict syntax and will fail if there's an extra class, or the classes are in a different order. Usually `>` and `[class="..."]` should be skipped unless there's good reason to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your `fill_stayDates` function.
I changed locator and also added logic that click should be performed on the last selector of buttons array (both arrow buttons have same selector, but forward button is always the last one.
Also I added `chooseDay` method that select day by element text exact match.

```js
  async function fill_stayDates(page, constants){
    const findMonth = async targetMonth => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        const month = await page.$eval('[id^="calendar-month-"]', el => el.textContent);
        if (month.includes(targetMonth)) break;

        const arrows = await page.$$('[data-testid="calendar-container"] > [class="flex justify-between"] button:not([disabled])');
        await arrows[arrows.length - 1].click();
      }
    };

      const chooseDay = async day => {
        const dayResult = await page.$$eval('button[id*=day-] span:not([class*=sr-only])', elements => elements.map(element => element.textContent));
        const dayIndex = dayResult.indexOf(`${day}`)
        await page.$$('button[id*=day-] span:not([class*=sr-only])').then(el => el[dayIndex].click());
      };

      await findMonth(constants.START_MONTH);
      await chooseDay(constants.START_DAY);
      await findMonth(constants.END_MONTH);
      await chooseDay(constants.END_DAY);

      await page.click('[class="stroke-text"]');
    };
}
```